# need to add max length to entity framework self-tracking entity template

Tags: entity-framework, t4, self-tracking-entities

I need to add max length to my self tracking entities
I have tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520/)

but it's done using the EntityObject Generator and not the Serf-Tracking Entity Generator

the template is very different, I have tried to cut and paste the code, but I always get the error message :

> A Statement cannot appear after the first class feature in the
>   template. Only boilerplate, expressions and other class features are
>   allowed after the first class feature block.

where do I need to add the code ?

```
private bool IsNullable(TypeUsage usage)
    {
        return (bool)usage.Facets.First(facet => facet.Name == "Nullable").Value;
    }

    private bool HasMaxLength(TypeUsage usage)
    {
        return usage.Facets.Any(facet => facet.Name == "MaxLength");    
    }

    private int MaxLength(TypeUsage usage)
    {
        return (int)usage.Facets.First(facet => facet.Name == "MaxLength").Value;    
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put that code at the end of the template and close it into `<#+ #>` block. The example for defining reusable methods is at the beginning of the article under *What can T4 templates do for me?*